# Hibernate Filter doesn't work as intended

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao

I have two classes where one of the class is inherited by the Entity which is used for implementing soft deletes. I have a DAO method which uses Entity with DeleteEnabledResource filter to enable filters. However hibernate doesn't seem to consider applying filters even though it's enabled properly (I can observe the filter enabled in debug view). I use Hibernate 4.3.8.Final. Adding DAO, Classes and Hibernate generated queries.

Note: This works perfectly fine for my other entities.

DAO

If I add one more criteria then filter is enabled and the deleted = 0 appears in the Hibernate generated queries.

```
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.enableFilter("DeleteEnabledResource");
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(WfWorkflows.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.naturalId().set("tenantId", tenantId).set("workflowId", workflowId).set("version", version));

        return (WfWorkflows) criteria.uniqueResult();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        LOGGER.debug("Tenant Id = {} | Workflow Id ={} | Version = {}  | Failed to get", tenantId, workflowId, version, exc);
        throw new DataAccessException(exc);
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Classes

DeleteEnabled Class

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;

@MappedSuperclass
@FilterDef(name = "DeleteEnabledResource", defaultCondition = "deleted = 0")
@Filter(name = "DeleteEnabledResource", condition = "deleted = 0")
public class DeleteEnabled {

    public DeleteEnabled() {
    }

    private boolean deleted = false;

    /**
     * Getter for property 'deleted'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'deleted'.
     */
    @Column(name = "deleted", columnDefinition = "BIT default 0")
    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'deleted'.
     *
     * @param deleted Value to set for property 'deleted'.
     */
    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
}
```

Workflow Class

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

/**
 * WfWorkflows represents a Workflow
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "wf_workflows", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"tenant_id", "workflow_id", "version"})})
public class WfWorkflows extends DeleteEnabled implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5901132323282824514L;

    private Integer id;
    private int version;
    private WfWorkflows inheritedId;
    private String workflowId;
    private long tenantId;
    private String flowName;
    private String description;
    private String workflowData;
    private Date dateCreated = new Date();
    private String createdBy;
    private Date dateModified;
    private String modifiedBy;
    private Set<WfWorkflows> inheritedIds = new HashSet<WfWorkflows>(0);
    private String status = null;

    /**
     * Constructs a new WfWorkflows.
     */
    public WfWorkflows() {
    }

    public WfWorkflows(String workflowId, int version, long tenantId, String flowName, String description) {
        this.workflowId = workflowId;
        this.version = version;
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
        this.flowName = flowName;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public WfWorkflows(String workflowId, int version, long tenantId, String flowName, String description, WfWorkflows inheritedId) {
        this.workflowId = workflowId;
        this.version = version;
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
        this.flowName = flowName;
        this.description = description;
        this.inheritedId = inheritedId;
    }

    public WfWorkflows(String workflowId, WfWorkflows inheritedId, int version, long tenantId, String flowName, String description, String workflowData) {
        this.workflowId = workflowId;
        this.inheritedId = inheritedId;
        this.version = version;
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
        this.flowName = flowName;
        this.description = description;
        this.workflowData = workflowData;
    }

    public WfWorkflows(int version, WfWorkflows inheritedId, String workflowId, long tenantId, String flowName, String description, Date dateCreated, String createdBy, Date dateModified, String modifiedBy) {
        this.version = version;
        this.inheritedId = inheritedId;
        this.workflowId = workflowId;
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
        this.flowName = flowName;
        this.description = description;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public WfWorkflows(int version, WfWorkflows inheritedId, String workflowId, long tenantId, String flowName, String description, String workflowData, Date dateCreated, String createdBy, Date dateModified, String modifiedBy) {
        this.version = version;
        this.inheritedId = inheritedId;
        this.workflowId = workflowId;
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
        this.flowName = flowName;
        this.description = description;
        this.workflowData = workflowData;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'id'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'id'.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'id'.
     *
     * @param id Value to set for property 'id'.
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'version'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'version'.
     */
    @NaturalId(mutable = false)
    @Column(name = "version", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT DEFAULT 1")
    public int getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'version'.
     *
     * @param version Value to set for property 'version'.
     */
    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'inheritedId'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'inheritedId'.
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inherited_id", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "INT")
    public WfWorkflows getInheritedId() {
        return this.inheritedId;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'inheritedId'.
     *
     * @param inheritedId Value to set for property 'inheritedId'.
     */
    public void setInheritedId(WfWorkflows inheritedId) {
        this.inheritedId = inheritedId;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'workflowId'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'workflowId'.
     */
    @NaturalId(mutable = false)
    @Column(name = "workflow_id", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getWorkflowId() {
        return this.workflowId;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'workflowId'.
     *
     * @param workflowId Value to set for property 'workflowId'.
     */
    public void setWorkflowId(String workflowId) {
        this.workflowId = workflowId;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'tenantId'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'tenantId'.
     */
    @NaturalId(mutable = false)
    @Column(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false)
    public long getTenantId() {
        return this.tenantId;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'tenantId'.
     *
     * @param tenantId Value to set for property 'tenantId'.
     */
    public void setTenantId(long tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'flowName'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'flowName'.
     */
    @Column(name = "flow_name", nullable = false, length = 200)
    public String getFlowName() {
        return this.flowName;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'flowName'.
     *
     * @param flowName Value to set for property 'flowName'.
     */
    public void setFlowName(String flowName) {
        this.flowName = flowName;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'description'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'description'.
     */
    @Column(name = "description", length = 500)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'description'.
     *
     * @param description Value to set for property 'description'.
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'workflowData'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'workflowData'.
     */
    @Column(name = "workflow_data", length = 65535, nullable = true, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    public String getWorkflowData() {
        return workflowData;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'workflowData'.
     *
     * @param workflowData Value to set for property 'workflowData'.
     */
    public void setWorkflowData(String workflowData) {
        this.workflowData = workflowData;
    }


    /**
     * Getter for property 'dateCreated'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'dateCreated'.
     */
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false, length = 19, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return this.dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'dateCreated'.
     *
     * @param dateCreated Value to set for property 'dateCreated'.
     */
    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'createdBy'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'createdBy'.
     */
    @Column(name = "created_by", length = 50)
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'createdBy'.
     *
     * @param createdBy Value to set for property 'createdBy'.
     */
    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'dateModified'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'dateModified'.
     */
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_modified", length = 19)
    public Date getDateModified() {
        return this.dateModified;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'dateModified'.
     *
     * @param dateModified Value to set for property 'dateModified'.
     */
    public void setDateModified(Date dateModified) {
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'modifiedBy'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'modifiedBy'.
     */
    @Column(name = "modified_by", length = 50)
    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return this.modifiedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'modifiedBy'.
     *
     * @param modifiedBy Value to set for property 'modifiedBy'.
     */
    public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }


    /**
     * Getter for property 'inheritedIds'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'inheritedIds'.
     */
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "inheritedId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<WfWorkflows> getInheritedIds() {
        return this.inheritedIds;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'inheritedIds'.
     *
     * @param inheritedIds Value to set for property 'inheritedIds'.
     */
    public void setInheritedIds(Set<WfWorkflows> inheritedIds) {
        this.inheritedIds = inheritedIds;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property 'status'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'status'.
     */
    @Column(name = "status")
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'status'.
     *
     * @param status Value to set for property 'status'.
     */
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

Hibernate Output (Generated Queries, missing deleted = 0 condition)

```
    Hibernate: insert into wf_workflows (deleted, created_by, date_created, date_modified, description, flow_name, inherited_id, modified_by, status, tenant_id, version, workflow_data, workflow_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select wfworkflow_.id as id1_21_ from wf_workflows wfworkflow_ where wfworkflow_.tenant_id=? and wfworkflow_.version=? and wfworkflow_.workflow_id=?
Hibernate: select wfworkflow0_.id as id1_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.deleted as deleted2_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.created_by as created_3_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.date_created as date_cre4_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.date_modified as date_mod5_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.description as descript6_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.flow_name as flow_nam7_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.inherited_id as inherit14_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.modified_by as modified8_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.status as status9_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.tenant_id as tenant_10_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.version as version11_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.workflow_data as workflo12_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.workflow_id as workflo13_21_0_, wfworkflow1_.id as id1_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.deleted as deleted2_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.created_by as created_3_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.date_created as date_cre4_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.date_modified as date_mod5_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.description as descript6_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.flow_name as flow_nam7_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.inherited_id as inherit14_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.modified_by as modified8_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.status as status9_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.tenant_id as tenant_10_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.version as version11_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.workflow_data as workflo12_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.workflow_id as workflo13_21_1_ from wf_workflows wfworkflow0_ left outer join wf_workflows wfworkflow1_ on wfworkflow0_.inherited_id=wfworkflow1_.id where wfworkflow0_.id=?
Hibernate: select inheritedi0_.inherited_id as inherit14_21_0_, inheritedi0_.id as id1_21_0_, inheritedi0_.id as id1_21_1_, inheritedi0_.deleted as deleted2_21_1_, inheritedi0_.created_by as created_3_21_1_, inheritedi0_.date_created as date_cre4_21_1_, inheritedi0_.date_modified as date_mod5_21_1_, inheritedi0_.description as descript6_21_1_, inheritedi0_.flow_name as flow_nam7_21_1_, inheritedi0_.inherited_id as inherit14_21_1_, inheritedi0_.modified_by as modified8_21_1_, inheritedi0_.status as status9_21_1_, inheritedi0_.tenant_id as tenant_10_21_1_, inheritedi0_.version as version11_21_1_, inheritedi0_.workflow_data as workflo12_21_1_, inheritedi0_.workflow_id as workflo13_21_1_ from wf_workflows inheritedi0_ where inheritedi0_.inherited_id=?
Hibernate: select wfworkflow0_.id as id1_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.deleted as deleted2_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.created_by as created_3_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.date_created as date_cre4_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.date_modified as date_mod5_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.description as descript6_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.flow_name as flow_nam7_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.inherited_id as inherit14_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.modified_by as modified8_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.status as status9_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.tenant_id as tenant_10_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.version as version11_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.workflow_data as workflo12_21_0_, wfworkflow0_.workflow_id as workflo13_21_0_, wfworkflow1_.id as id1_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.deleted as deleted2_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.created_by as created_3_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.date_created as date_cre4_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.date_modified as date_mod5_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.description as descript6_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.flow_name as flow_nam7_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.inherited_id as inherit14_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.modified_by as modified8_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.status as status9_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.tenant_id as tenant_10_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.version as version11_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.workflow_data as workflo12_21_1_, wfworkflow1_.workflow_id as workflo13_21_1_ from wf_workflows wfworkflow0_ left outer join wf_workflows wfworkflow1_ on wfworkflow0_.inherited_id=wfworkflow1_.id where wfworkflow0_.id=?
Hibernate: select inheritedi0_.inherited_id as inherit14_21_0_, inheritedi0_.id as id1_21_0_, inheritedi0_.id as id1_21_1_, inheritedi0_.deleted as deleted2_21_1_, inheritedi0_.created_by as created_3_21_1_, inheritedi0_.date_created as date_cre4_21_1_, inheritedi0_.date_modified as date_mod5_21_1_, inheritedi0_.description as descript6_21_1_, inheritedi0_.flow_name as flow_nam7_21_1_, inheritedi0_.inherited_id as inherit14_21_1_, inheritedi0_.modified_by as modified8_21_1_, inheritedi0_.status as status9_21_1_, inheritedi0_.tenant_id as tenant_10_21_1_, inheritedi0_.version as version11_21_1_, inheritedi0_.workflow_data as workflo12_21_1_, inheritedi0_.workflow_id as workflo13_21_1_ from wf_workflows inheritedi0_ where inheritedi0_.inherited_id=?
Hibernate: delete from wf_workflows where id=?
```

Comment: my guess is this is because you're only selecting on `@NaturalId`s. For such a "direct" read it arguably makes no sense to apply additional filters, although I can't find any documentation on when filters are or are not applied. In your other entities (where you say it is working), do you have more criteria?

Comment: I have similar entity that has `@NaturalId`'s only and that particular one works just fine. Same here, I couldn't find any documentation on the matter!